# Capturing and redirecting outgoing traffic from given ip:port to target ip:port

Tags: windows-7, tcp, ssh-tunnel

On Windows 7 I have an SSH tunnel running on my local `127.0.0.1:34567` address that I need to access so I can access `12.34.56.78:8080` with the help of SSH proxying for me as I cannot access that IP directly (due to not being on the whitelist).

My basic simple goal therefore is that on Windows whenever I request `12.34.56.78:8080` from anywhere (my browser for instance), I would like the request to instead be diverted to `127.0.0.1:34567` transparently, and I would like a software solution to this instead of a hardware one if possible. I think this is what's usually achieved in Linux by something called iptables, but I'm looking for something I can use on windows.

Does anyone know how this is possible? If I need to use any external Windows program for this, that is fine, but I prefer it to be free.

**EDIT:** please do not present me with reverse tunnel solutions. My goal is to request the same ip:port that I'm blocked from, but to be able to get to that ip:port successfully through the means of my existing SSH tunnel. Reverse tunnels involve requesting a different ip:port which is not what I'm looking for (I already have a forward tunnel I can use if I wanted to make requests to a different ip:port).

**Example scenario:** Pretend that you have an C-compiled `.exe` file whose source code you don't have access to that is hardcoded to request `12.34.56.78:8000` for SOAP webservices. The problem is, your IP is blocked from that ip:port, but you do have access to an SSH server which isn't blocked by `210.212.239.117:8080` and also have an SSH tunnel set up for that SSH server to access that ip:port... but your `.exe` has the original ip:port hardcoded, so you can't just tell it to request the SSH tunnel ip:port, as it's not possible to change the ip:port to be requested in any way due to it being hardcoded! You would have to have the request to `210.212.239.117:8080` on your computer somehow diverted to your SSH tunnel on the OS level. So how would you get that done?

**EDIT 2:** I'm not looking for routing tables either (I think). I don't want to modify the route my request goes through to reach target ip:port; I actually want to have the requested ip and port themselves silently changed. I kind of want to achieve something like the `hosts` file, except instead of resolving hostnames to ips, I want ip:ports to be reresolved to different ip:ports.

**Bounty:** Sorry, it appears this stackoverflow question of mine counts as Offtopic and isn't eligable for offering a bounty, so sorry to anyone who put in extra work and would have potentially received the bounty!

Comment: Just to clarify reverse tunnel or port forwarding needs physical access nothing else.

Comment: For setting one up, maybe, but to use the reverse proxy, I would have to request an ip:port different than the one I am blocked from, I think. And if so, it's not something that I'm looking for.

Comment: Isn't this something like this:http://blog.peter-b.org/2011/08/01/using-iptables-to-map-an-internal-address-to-an-external-one/? Or this:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table?

Comment: For the first one: I think so. But for Windows, not Linux. The second one: no. I'm not looking to find the route to the IP I want to send to. I want to actually silently have the target IP rewritten to a completely different IP.

Comment: There is this answer:http://serverfault.com/questions/207620/windows-equivalent-of-iptables.

Comment: I've already looked into the Windows GUI firewall settings and I was only able to either allow connections or block connections, not divert connections. The documentation for the CLI tool (`netsh advfirewall`) also does not seem to mention diverting connection attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a ready executable, but [WFPSampler](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Filtering-Platform-27553baa#content) seems to be promising. It uses the new Windows Filtering Platform API (available since Windows Vista) to manipulate packets.

To use it for redirecting outgoing packets, give a look at [Q&A section](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Filtering-Platform-27553baa/view/Discussions#content), there are many examples.

Comment: Nice API you found there ! I beleive you have the answer to the OP question. Have you tried building the sample (with the sdk/wdk alone, maybe) ?

Comment: May I ask that you give me a sample of what command I have to run to get my example scenario working?
I can't try this program out right now, but I know it's going to take me a long time just to compile this (as there doesn't appear to be a readily usable executable), and figuring out which executable to call with which arguments I might not have time left for, especially with my limited knowledge of networking. If it's not too much to ask. The Q&A seems way too complicated as well.

Comment: No problem, in the Q&A section the user _d-gojo_ provided a command to redirect a TCP connection based on the destination port and the executable which establishes it to a different LAN IP address and port.

Here it is:

`WFPSampler.exe -s PROXY -l FWPM_LAYER_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4 -aaid "<path of iexplore.exe>" -iprp 443 -pra 192.168.1.10 -prp 0x22B8 -prs -v -wi`

You probably won't need the `-aaid` option, instead you should add an `-ipra` (IP remote address) and specify your IP target. Also, remove `-prs` option and change `pra` and `prp`, the new IP address and port.

Comment: I will integrate all this to the answer, as soon as I try it.

Comment: So would it be `WFPSampler.exe -s PROXY -l FWPM_LAYER_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4 -ipra 12.34.56.78 -iprp 8080 -pra 127.0.0.1 -prp 34567 -v -wi`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse shell. It can mirror a remote port. Use ssh to connect with -R option. For example ssh -R xxxx:localhost:xxxx user:pass@www.server.com. Check this out:http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html.

Comment: I think your syntax was a bit incorrect. With a bit of modification, did you mean `ssh -R 12.34.56.78:8080:127.0.0.1:34567 user@www.server.com`? It didn't work under my windows; it said: Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 80

I also tried `ssh -R 141.101.120.14:80:127.0.0.1:80 user@example.com`, where `example.com` is some working SSH server, and `141.101.120.14` is whatismyip.com's IP. I got `Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 80` and http://www.whatismyip.com/ did not result in my local webserver as I expected.

Comment: @SzerémiAttila:No,it's absolute correct:http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Telnet/SSH_and_the_Command_Line#SSH_Port_Forwarding

Comment: I've read it. The Local Port Forwarding section is about SSH tunnels which I know isn't what I need (I already have one anyway). The Remote Port Forwarding looks like it involves routers. I'm looking for a windows solution. Please read my question.

Comment: @SzerémiAttila:Can you elaborate? Where is a router needed? You can also use PuTTY on Windows. Here is another link:http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html.

Comment: I thought my question was clear enough, but to give a better hint about what I need, let's pretend "127.0.0.1" can never be involved.
Let's say I want it so if I request `91.190.218.46:80` (skype.com) from any software on my computer (browser, or cygwin wget), I want the request diverted silently to `210.212.239.117:8080` (some random person's tomcat server) and get the contents of the latter ip-port's index html when requesting the former ip-port. If you could tell me how to achieve this without involving localhost, then with tool I should be able to achieve what I need.

Comment: @SzerémiAttila:When you can access ssh on 210.212.239.117 then you can   do this with a port forwarding or a remote shell. BTW. I'm not an expert I just want to help. It seems to me your question is too vague.  Anyway you can read about port forwarding and remote shell. Maybe you understand it latter.

Comment: there's no SSH or listening (in the traditional sense) to be involved. When I request `91.190.218.46:80` I want to receive `210.212.239.117:8080`. For the sake of simplicity, pretend the the hosts file doesn't exist. I want to be able to make it so that if I request `skype.com`, I am met with `210.212.239.117:8080`, while the browser URL still says `skype.com`. How do I achieve that? If you think firewalls, firewalls let you choose outgoing IPs and have then either a) be blocked, or b) let them go through. I'm looking for a third options, c) divert that ip:port to target ip:port

Comment: @SzerémiAttila:A hosts file can do this. I'm not sure what you are looking for. It seems you need this BarbaTunnel thing. Good luck!

Comment: the reason I used hostnames in my ***examples*** was for simplicity. In reality, all services I am actually using do not have hostnames, only IPs, so the hosts file is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out BarbaTunnel: http://barbatunnel.codeplex.com/

TCP-Redirect mode is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: This does not quite seem to let me achieve what I need. It does look a bit complicated though so I might just not be understanding it. I was looking at the config help: http://barbatunnel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=config.ini
And I noticed there is only one option that accepts only 1 IP address and that is `ServerAddress`. I am expecting 2 IP address options, 1 for what outgoing IP requests to capture and another for what IP to divert the request to. Please read my updated question.

Comment: From what I read, I guess you may not be able to selectively capture and redirect traffic going to a certain port on a certain IP address, it only allows you capture traffic going to a certain port on all IP addresses. Also, it does not let you say to which IP address you want to redirect to, it only allows you to redirect to localhost. So you set RealPort to the TCP port number to be captured, you set TunnelPort to the localhost listening port number (you opened with `ssh -L`), and it will redirect *:RealPort to 127.0.0.1:TunnelPort.

Comment: But, the software is open-source, and it is based on a generic packet filtering/mangling library. It does sound reasonable that this software could be extended to limit this redirection to traffic destined only to a single IP address, if you really need that functionality. Or you could simply drop 95% of the code, and hardwire the logic you want.

Comment: Well, my SSH tunnels will always be running on localhost so it's not so bad if it always diverts to localhost, but it is bad if it captures requests to all IP addresses using the port I give instead of just that one IP address as there are many unrelated services using port `8080` that I wouldn't want diverted at all. Unfortunately I do not know C# and I do not wish to get this deep into the subject as I really hope there already exists some software that already does all this. Thank you though.

Comment: And it requires a server component, which falls outside the OP's requirements, doesn't it ?

Comment: @ixe013: To me, the difference between TCP-Tunnel & TCP-Redirect modes looks like as if TCP-Tunnel required a server component, whereas TCP-Redirect did not. But the documentation is not that clear about that, I agree. And I haven't tested that piece of software.