# Exclude localhost from bind redirect

Tags: windows, winapi, wfp

I'm using [WFPSampler](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/trans/WFPSampler) to redirect all traffic to a specific interface by using command:

```
WFPSampler.exe -s PROXY -l FWPM_LAYER_ALE_BIND_REDIRECT_V4 -pla 10.0.2.15 -v -in
```

This works just fine, traffic from all of the processes is redirected as expected. The only problem is that it binds **127.0.0.1** to **10.0.2.15** as well and then some applications fail to connect.

For example, I've created simple Python HTTP server on **127.0.0.1:8000** and I can not access it over the browser using this address.

I know that on `FWPM_LAYER_ALE_BIND_REDIRECT_V4` it is only possible to filter by local address, but I have somehow to filter by remote address at this point to avoid binding localhost to **10.0.2.15**

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the outgoing traffic from 10.0.2.15 to 127.0.0.1 at the same time, with the command like:

```
WFPSampler.exe -s PROXY -l FWPM_LAYER_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4 -ipra 10.0.2.15 -pra 127.0.0.1 -v -in
```

The comments of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294700/capturing-and-redirecting-outgoing-traffic-from-given-ipport-to-target-ipport) has metioned it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, I get **ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID** when trying to access **127.0.0.1:8000**